# Insert records into database and at the same time notify users about number of record inserted or failed in node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

I have a requirement like this:

Maximum 500 records.

1. I have to insert records into a table.  However, before inserting them I have to check if that same record or it's parents are already inserted.
2. **Want to achieve:-** How can i notify the user at the same time once the record is inserted in node.js
   Example:- if i am uploading 400 records and 5 records are inserted user should be notified that 5 record is inserted if any failed, failed record count should be notified.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @Igor, I don't expect code. If you have idea that how can i notify users instantly once record inserted? because if i send result i wouldn't' be able to send it again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Igor already told you how to make a question so you should pass through what he righted.
Now answering your question , you need basically control the insertion. And use 2 counters, for example: `let inserted , let notInserted` or `var inserted , var notInserted`

- For each insertion you check if exists , if yes notInserted +1 else inserted+1
  At the end you should return to user the result `res.send().json({message:"Inserted"+ inserted+"Not Inserted"+notInserted}) ;`

Something like this!

Comment: I don't have to notify at once. I have to notify one by one.Thanks

Comment: use the `ngOnChanges()` to do it